# How do you configure a ColdFusion 8 datasource to connect to a local SQL Server 2008 server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, datasource, sql-server-express, coldfusion-8

I've set up a local SQL 2008 Server, enabled SQL Authentication, created a user for ColdFusion to use and verified that I can connect with that username and password using SSMS.  (Connect using MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS)

However, I am unable to successfuly add the datasource in my CF Administrator, with the error being: Error establishing socket to host and port

Is there additional configuration of the server or ColdFusion that is necessary to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use LOCALHOST as the server name, and port 1433 as the port number. You may have to enable IP connections through the SQL Server Configuration Manager. You can search Google for instructions on how to do that, which I [found here](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/162) and [here](http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/local-sql-server-2008-coldfusion-datasource/).

Comment: Ah I turned off dynamic ports but forgot to specify one to use.  1433 worked perfectly, thank you!